# How do i give ID numbers a consecutive number in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a dataset of different firms with their year of observation and other relevant information.

How do I sort the data by ID number and then add consecutive numbers based on the observation year?

For example if the data looks like this:

```
ID number    Year of observation 
-------------------------------------
ABC          2004
ABC          2005
ABC          2006
ABC          2007
DEF          2005
DEF          2006
```

How can I do this in SPSS?

```
ID number    Year of observation     Observation number
ABC          2004                    1 
ABC          2005                    2
ABC          2006                    3
ABC          2007                    4
DEF          2005                    1
DEF          2006                    2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sort cases by ID year.
compute obsNum=1.
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) obsNum=lag(obsNum)+1.
```

Comment: I tried it but the 'obsNum' is empty

Comment: Probably just need to run pending transformations. You can add an `execute.` command to do it. Read [here](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-execute-command/) about execute and pending transformations